# Magento Save order before submit

Tags: magento-1.8, onepage-checkout

A client I'm working for wants to have order saved right after entering payment information (one page checkout). The status should be 'during_payment', but the status is not a problem. The problem is I don't know how to save order after that step, and then make magento just update the existing order with new payment information and status in case the payment succeded. Any ideas would be very welcome! Thanks!